# MS CRM - Organization table having multiple records

Tags: dynamics-crm

I'm working with MS CRM 2015. Some of my Organization data base having multiple records in the Organization Table. Looks like whenever I do database backup and restore and then org import, it is creating additional entries in Organization table, but not deleting or disabling the old entry. Sometimes this record count increases more when we do multiple backup-restore-imports. Not sure how CRM handles this.

Now one of the Organization import not working. Org import dint give any error, but when we try to access the CRM UI, it throws error as "The user ID associated with the current record is not valid". But user is available in the Source organization and source and target organizations both in the same domain etc. Looks like multiple times of Org import messed up some CRM config data. Anybody have any idea?

Error from Event log is,

> Exception information: 
>       Exception type: CrmException 
>       Exception message: The user Id is invalid.    at Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.SecurityLibrary.GetPrivilegedUserCallerAndBusinessGuidsFromThread(WindowsIdentity
>   identity, IOrganizationContext context)    at
>   Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.SecurityLibrary.GetCallerAndBusinessGuidsFromThread(WindowsIdentity
>   identity, Guid organizationId, LocatorServiceContext
>   locatorServiceContext)